# Solo pegar en un JTextField

Tags: java, java-swing

Necesito hacer en Java, que en un JTextField solo se puedan copiar datos, es decir:

- que no permita ingresar datos directamente desde el teclado
- solo permita que se copie un dato de otro lado y se pegue en el JTextField.

¿Esto es posible?

Comment: No encuentro ahora mismo documentación que lo sustente, pero leí que al poner el `JTextField` como deshabilitado no admitiría entradas del teclado, pero se puede pegar texto en él. Es cuestión de probar: `myJTextfield.setEnabled(false);`

Comment: chequea este vinculo, debe aclararte la duda q tienes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21695175/jtextfield-setenabled-vs-seteditable

Comment: En todo caso no sería mejor meterlo en un JCombobox? de cualquier forma puede escribir lo que quiera y pegarlo en el JTextField si lo haces de esa manera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JTextField` por defecto crea una interfaz keymap tambien referenciada como [`DEFAULT_KEYMAP`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Keymap.html).
Un `Keymap` (compartido por todas las instancias `JTextComponent`) le permite a una aplicación unir pulsaciones de teclas a acciones; Dentro de esas acciones mínimo se encuentran:

1. Insertar contenido en el campo cuando se trate de teclas
   imprimibles.
2. Eliminar contenido con las teclas Backspace o Del.
3. Mover el cursor parpadeante adelante o hacia atrás.

**Pasando** `null` a [`setKeymap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setKeymap(javax.swing.text.Keymap)) queda **inactiva** la entrada por teclado pero aun con la posibilidad de pegar los datos desde el clipboard.

`miCampo.setKeymap(null);`

---

*Fuente: [Documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html) de `JTextComponent`.*

Comment: Poniendo el setKeymap() en null, pude hacer lo que necesitaba. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

se puede mediante el método:

```
jTextField = new JTextField();
jTextField.setEditable(false); //no permite editar "a mano", pero si copiar
jTextField.setText("test2"); // ejemplo de edición aceptado
```

Comment: Lo que ocurre con setEditable(false) es que pierdes el 'focus' del componente y no se puede hacer un CTRL+C / CTRL+V, por ejemplo.

Comment: @Johnny eso NO esta especificado en la pregunta original. Por lo tanto lo que respondí si es válido.

Comment: Jamas he dicho que esa respuesta está errada!, simplemente he contemplado el escenario en donde se traiga info del portapapeles y pueda 'pegarse' en el campo. Es más, te daré +1 para nivelar el downvote que te dieron. Feliz weekend!.